# Replace key of array with the value of another array while looping through

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional arrays. First one `$properties` contains english names and their values. My second array contains the translations. An example

```
$properties[] = array(array("Floor"=>"5qm"));
$properties[] = array(array("Height"=>"10m"));

$translations[] = array(array("Floor"=>"Boden"));
$translations[] = array(array("Height"=>"Höhe"));
```

(They are multidimensional because the contains more elements, but they shouldn't matter now)

Now I want to translate this Array, so that I its at the end like this:

```
$properties[] = array(array("Boden"=>"5qm"));
$properties[] = array(array("Höhe"=>"10m"));
```

I have managed to build the foreach construct to loop through these arrays, but at the end it is not translated, the problem is, how I tell the array to replace the key with the value.

What I have done is this:

```
//Translate Array
foreach ($properties as $PropertyArray) {
    //need second foreach because multidimensional array
    foreach ($PropertyArray as $P_KiviPropertyNameKey => $P_PropertyValue) {
        foreach ($translations as $TranslationArray) {
            //same as above
            foreach ($TranslationArray as $T_KiviTranslationPropertyKey => $T_KiviTranslationValue) {
                if ($P_KiviPropertyNameKey == $T_KiviTranslationPropertyKey) {
                    //Name found, save new array key
                    $P_KiviPropertyNameKey = $T_KiviTranslationValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is with the line where to save the new key:

```
$P_KiviPropertyNameKey = $T_KiviTranslationValue;
```

I know this part is executed correctly and contains the correct variables, but I believe this is the false way to assing the new key.

This is the way it should be done:

```
$properties[$oldkey] = $translations[$newkey];
```

So I tried this one:

```
$PropertyArray[$P_KiviPropertyNameKey] = $TranslationArray[$T_KiviTranslationPropertyKey];
```

As far as I understood, the above line should change the P_KiviPropertyNameKey of the PropertyArray into the value of Translation Array but I do not receive any error nor is the name translated. How should this be done correctly?

Thank you for any help!

**Additional info**

This is a live example of the properties array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [country_id] => 4402
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [iv_person_phone] => 03-11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [companyperson_lastname] => Kallio
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [rc_lot_area_m2] => 2412.7
        )
    [56] => Array
        (
            [floors] => 3
        )

    [57] => Array
        (
            [total_area_m2] => 97.0
        )

    [58] => Array
        (
            [igglo_silentsale_realty_flag] => false
        )

    [59] => Array
        (
            [possession_partition_flag] => false
        )

    [60] => Array
        (
            [charges_parkingspace] => 10
        )

    [61] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [image_realtyimagetype_id] => yleiskuva
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [image_itemimagetype_name] => kivirealty-original
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [image_desc] => makuuhuone
                )
        )
)
```

And this is a live example of the translations array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [addr_region_area_id] => Maakunta
            [group] => Kohde
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [addr_town_area] => Kunta
            [group] => Kohde
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [arable_no_flag] => Ei peltoa
            [group] => Kohde
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [arableland] => Pellon kuvaus
            [group] => Kohde
        )
)
```

I can build the translations array in another way. I did this like this, because in the second step I have to check, which group the keys belong to...

Comment: Thx! I want to replace the key of $properties with the value of $translations

Comment: Is the array always one child deep ?

Comment: Noo unfortunatedly not... I thought first get the first childs translated, then worry about the second lvl...

Comment: @Kaktus, just out of interest, could you display one example of how the structure is of a _complete_ array assigned to `$properties[]`? Because an `array,array,array` somehow seems ambiguous to me .. Second, how come the structure of the `$translations` array is just like the `$properties` array? Wouldn't it be easier to have a translation array that's based on the key?

Comment: I added an live example... The key names do not match in the example because I took only a little part, but they match in the real array ...  What did you mean with *Wouldn't it be easier to have a translation array that's based on the key?* I'd love to hear anything which makes this easier!!

Comment: @Kaktus: Did you check my code? do some response or else dont post the questions..

Comment: Why isn't the translations array two-dimensional? i.e. `[['Height' => 'Hohe'], ['Floor' => 'Boden']]`

Comment: Sorry @Vinoth Babu there are so many answers I was all the time commenting and trying the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the structure of `$properties` and `$translations`, you somehow know how these are connected. It's a bit vague how the indices of the array match eachother, meaning the values in `$properties` at index `0` is the equivalent for the translation in `$translations` at index `0`.

I'm just wondering why the `$translations` array need to have the same structure (in nesting) as the `$properties` array. To my opinion the word `Height` can only mean `Höhe` in German. Representing it as an array would suggest there are multiple translations possible.

So if you could narrow down the `$translations` array to an one dimensional array as in:

```
$translation = array(
  "Height"=>"Höhe",
  "Floor"=>"Boden"
);
```

A possible loop would be

```
$result = array();

foreach($properties as $i => $array2) {
  foreach($array2 as $i2 => $array3) {
    foreach($array3 as $key => $value) {
      $translatedKey = array_key_exists($key, $translations) ?
        $translations[$key]:
        $key;
      $result[$i][$i2][$translatedKey] = $value;
    }
  }
}
```

(I see every body posting 2 loops, it's an `array,array,array` structure, not `array,array` ..)

If you cannot narrow down the translation array to a one dimensional array, then I'm just wondering if each index in the `$properties` array matches the same index in the `$translations` array, if so it's the same trick by adding the indices (location):

```
$translatedKey = $translations[$i][$i2][$key];
```

I've used `array_key_exists` because I'm not sure a translation key is always present. You have to create the logic for each case scenario yourself on what to check or not.

Comment: Thank you all so much! I believe I really made it too complicated. As you suggested, its better to make 3 one dimensional arrays, first translate the first array, then compare it to the groups (the groups were not mentioned in the example)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$properties     = array();
$translations   = array();

$properties[]   = array("Floor"=>"5qm");
$properties[]   = array("Height"=>"10m");

$translations[] = array("Floor"=>"Boden");
$translations[] = array("Height"=>"Höhe");

$temp           = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $translations);

$result         = array();
foreach($properties as $key=>$val){
   foreach($val as $k=>$v){
       $result[$key][$temp[$k]] = $v;
   }  
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Boden] => 5qm
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Höhe] => 10m
        )

)
```

**Please note** : I changed the array to `$properties[]   = array("Floor"=>"5qm");`, Removed a level of array, I guess this is how you need to structure your array.

Comment: Thank you it works fine in your example, but unfortunatedly the arrays are multidimensional.. I could probably divert them, make of the group a third array, but its important that its the most effective way to handle this because its about a huge xml file. How can I translate your example into mine?

Comment: The TS has more then one child.

Comment: In my answer arays are alredy two dimensional...Why exactly you need it to be multi ?

Comment: Wow your right, I works! I am so thankful! But I receive some errors, I believe there are few line which do not have any translation. Two times `Notice: Undefined index:` (I believe these are the two with missing translations) and a `Warning: Illegal offset type` .. This one I do not understand. (All errors refer to the `$result[$key][$temp[$k]] = $v;` line.)

Comment: hmmmm...if you dont have translation it will show error, We can remove this error by checking array_key_exists, but then the corresponding value will not be displayed, it is better to add translation value.

Comment: thank you.. The problem is, I need the second values of the translation array saved too. My fault I did not include it into the example, I thought the translations array remain the same...

Answer (score 0):

This is a fully recursive way to do it.

```
 /* input */
$properties[] = array(array("Floor"=>"5qm", array("Test"=>"123")));
$properties[] = array(array("Height"=>"10m"));

$translations[] = array(array("Floor"=>"Boden", array("Test"=>"Foo")));
$translations[] = array(array("Height"=>"Höhe"));


function array_flip_recursive($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $arr[$key] = array_flip_recursive($val);
        }
        else {
           $arr = @array_flip($arr);
       }
    }
    return $arr;
}

function array_merge_it($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $arr[$key] = array_merge_it($val);
        } else {
            if(isset($arr[$key]) && !empty($arr[$key])) {
              @$arr[$key] = $arr[$val];
            }
        }
     }
    return $arr;
}

function array_delete_empty($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $arr[$key] = array_delete_empty($val);
        }
        else {
           if(empty($arr[$key])) {
             unset($arr[$key]);
           }
       }
    }
    return $arr;
}



$arr = array_replace_recursive($properties, $translations);
$arr = array_flip_recursive($arr);
$arr = array_replace_recursive($arr, $properties);
$arr = array_merge_it($arr);
$arr = array_delete_empty($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d2f92605b609b9739964ece9a4d8f389be4a7b81

Answer (score -1):

You have to do the for loop in this way. If i understood you right (i.e) in associative array first key is same (some index).

```
foreach($properties as $key => $values) {
    foreach($values as $key1 => $value1) {
        $propertyResult[] = array($translations[$key][$key1][$value1] => $properties[$key][$key1][$value1]);
    }
}

print_r($propertyResult);
```

Comment: `$values` will give you `array(array("Floor"=>"5qm"))`, `$values1` will give you `array("Floor"=>"5qm")`, using `$value1` as in `$translations[$key][$key1][$value1]` will throw a warning `Illegal offset type`. If you post a comment to the OP saying _do some response or else dont post the questions_, then please do post some decent valid code the next time.

Comment: @dbf: Dont you have eyes. See the code properly. It is not $values1, it is $value1.  Open your eyes lyk f--king and see it correctly..

Comment: I would would hate this world too, being you.